# "Which is equivalent for restricted x values to"

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, wolfram-alpha

I've been checking my homework via Wolfram Alpha, and for several questions (example below) in this section (trigonometric integrals). I'd be correct up until the last step, in which Wolfram  Alpha pulls a complete switcharoo, stating `"Which is equivalent for restricted x values to:..."`

Can you please explain this to me? What restricted x values? (no restriction was specified). How would I know to do this?
[image]

Comment: First of all, did you have any boundaries for the original integral ? You realise you cannot integrate $\tan$ anywhere you want ?

Comment: The exact question (and query I entered into WRA) was `integral of tan^3xdx`. I know it can't be integrated everywhere, but I don't understand how (in this example) `tan^2x` and `sec^2x` can be equivalent. (The famous identity `tan^2x + 1 = sec^2x` requires addition of 1, which is absent here.)

Comment: Oh, if that's the source of your concern, I guess Wolfram Alpha put the 1 in the "constant" term

Comment: Oh yeah! One last question: why bother making the switch? Answer that and repost your previous comment as an answer, and i'll accept them.

Comment: I'm doing this only because I don't like unanswered questions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment, Wolfram Alpha used the formula $tan^2x + 1 = sec^2x$ and put the 1 in the constant term to "simplify" the last . As for why WA did that, I believe they want to give you as many different expressions of the same quantity as they can so you can use whichever you prefer / whichever the exercice asks you to find.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\tan(x)$ has vertical asymptotes for $$x = \pm \frac{\pi}{2} + 2 \pi n$$

Hence we cannot integrate the function $\tan(x)$ in an interval that includes one or more of these points. Hence, we can only integrate over limited intervals, which is what is meant by *for restricted x values*.

Comment: I don't understand how (in this example) `tan^2x` and `sec^2x` can be equivalent. (The famous identity `tan^2x + 1 = sec^2x` requires addition of 1, which is absent here.)